# Сosts Export to GA via Management API does not work - status code 404

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I use GA Management API for daily costs export to my account. Everything worked well for a long time, but on October 22nd everything broke. I am getting error - 404.

- I did not find any information about the changes in the [GA Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData)
- I am using the latest version of the [official python library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) and it gives an **HttpError** with status code 404.

I also get a 500 error when using the APIs explorer, so I decided to ask the google engineers... Is everything okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing exactly the same. A set of different `uploadData` calls to the Management API, done in Google App Script, stopped working on October 22nd. All return 404 code.

This is the ticket in GA Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171492112